# How to find line with regex and remove any preceding lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for way to remove every lines before line which contains specific string in multiline string like this:

```
string1 
string2
string3
==== bump
string4
string5
string6
==== bump
```

But only first matching one...

At the end I would like to have this as an output:

```
==== bump
string4
string5
string6
==== bump
```

Comment: So what you do want the output to look like?

Comment: Could be: 
`==== bump
string4
string5
string6
==== bump`

or just
`string4
string5
string6
==== bump`

Sorry forgot to write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
text = '''\
string1 
string2
string3
==== bump
string4
string5
string6
==== bump'''

print(re.split(r'(=== bump)', text, maxsplit=1)[-1])
```

yields

```
string4
string5
string6
==== bump
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import io
import itertools
import sys

lines = io.StringIO(u'''\
string1 
string2
string3
==== bump
string4
string5
string6
==== bump
''')

sep = '==== bump'
it = itertools.dropwhile(lambda line: not line.startswith(sep), lines)
sys.stdout.writelines(it)
```

Output

```
==== bump
string4
string5
string6
==== bump
```

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative Language: Use Perl's Flip-Flop Operator

Assuming that you've stored your text in */tmp/corpus*, you could use the following Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\A==== bump/ ... /\A==== bump/' /tmp/corpus
```

This leverages the power of Perl's [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators). If you want to capture the output from Perl within your Python program, you can use the [Python subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. For example:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(
    "perl -ne 'print if /\A==== bump/ ... /\A==== bump/' /tmp/corpus",
    shell=True)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = '''
string1 
string2
string3
==== bump
string4
string5
string6
==== bump
'''

import re
sep = '==== bump'
matched = re.search('{0}.*?{0}'.format(re.escape(sep)), lines, flags=re.S)
print(matched.group(0))
```